# Asymptotics of Sequence Given Asymptotics of Counting Function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Let $(a_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence, and let $P(x) := \# \{a_n \mid a_n \le x \}$ be the corresponding counting function.

We are given that

$$
P(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}
$$

from which we want to deduce that

$$
a_n \sim n \log n
$$

---

I am a bit stuck as to how to progress with this. I have tried starting with the fact that $P(a_n) = n$ which gives us that

$$
\frac{a_n}{\log a_n} \sim n
$$

but since $\frac{x}{\log x}$ is not easily invertible (i.e. we would have to use something like the Lambert W function), this is not as straightforward as hoped.

Working backwards, it is easy to show that, if we denote $b_n := n \log n$, then

$$
\frac{b_n}{\log b_n} \sim n \sim \frac{a_n}{\log a_n}
$$

But can we deduce from this that $a_n \sim b_n$? (For what it's worth, I know that the converse of this is true.)

Comment: $a_n \sim \frac{a_n}{\log a_n} \log \frac{a_n}{\log a_n}\sim n \log n$

Comment: @reuns Ah yes, of course! If you want to write this as an answer (albeit a very straightforward one), I would be happy to accept it.